# Laravel - How to resolve total internal error when value is NULL

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code:

```
public function findScore(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->where('is_current', 1)
                    ->first()
                    ->id;

    $child = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->first();

    $parentid = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                    ->select('parent_id')
                    ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->where('id', $request->id)
                    ->first()
                    ->parent_id;

    $childid = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->where('id', $request->id)
                    ->first()
                    ->id;

   if(empty($child)) {
       abort(404);
   }

   $weightedscore = 0;
   $weightedscore = DB::table('appraisal_goals')
                        ->select(DB::raw("IFNULL(SUM(weighted_score),0) as weighted_score"))
                        ->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities)
                        ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
                        ->where('parent_id', $parentid)
                        ->first();

   $weightedscorex = 0;
   $weightedscorex = DB::table('appraisal_goals')
                        ->select('weighted_score')
                        ->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities)
                        ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
                        ->where('id', $childid)
                        ->first();

   $maxscore = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                    ->select('max_score')
                    ->find($child->parent_id);

   return response()->json([
        'maxscore' => $maxscore->max_score,
        'weightedscore' => $weightedscore->weighted_score,
        'weightedscorex' => $weightedscorex->weighted_score
    ]);
}
```

When I run the code, I got this error:

> jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8888/laraproject/get/findScore?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Then I found out that the error is on this line:

```
$weightedscorex = DB::table('appraisal_goals')
                    ->select('weighted_score')
                    ->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities)
                    ->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
                    ->where('id', $childid)
                    ->first();
```

because the value is null and the table is empty.

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to `return` the `abort(404)` don't you? Otherwise execution will continue I believe. (check the docs or source to confirm, but I don't think it die()s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to return the [`abort`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-abort) as

> The abort function throws an HTTP exception which will be rendered by the exception handler:

You may do it so by

```
if(is_null($child)) {
   return response()->json([
       'message' => 'Child not found'
   ], 404);
}
```

or if you'd wanna use `abort` just make sure your request expect a json response.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
    },
    ...
});
```

PS:

```
$parentid = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                ->select('parent_id')
                ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->first()
                ->parent_id;

$childid = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                ->where('id', $request->id)
                ->first()
                ->id;
```

the above query is unnecesssary as you could get the attribute from the child object as `$child->parent_id` and `$child->id`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
   if(empty($child))
```

to:

```
   if(is_null($child))
```

also, you can refactor your code for example you can do this:

```
    $appraisal_goal_type = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('id', 'parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id', $request->id)->first();
    // so you can use $appraisal_goal_type->parent_id; instead of $parentid
    // so you can use $appraisal_goal_type->id; instead of $childid
```

---

### UPDATE

The right solution is :

```
    if(is_null($child) || is_null($childid))
    {
        abort(404);
    }
```

Comment: `empty` also checks for `null` FYI

Comment: You are mistaken two things. In the code, there is $child and also $childid.  $childis is in the one causing error.  Thanks

Comment: Yes [mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387/mpen) empty checks for null too I updated my answer, [mikefolu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12510040/mikefolu) you are right I just see your reply, thanks.